# Compile R script into standalone .exe file?

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to compile my `R` script into standalone `.exe` file just like what matlab does?

Comment: Very short answer: No. Never has been.

Comment: Actually I would like to distribe it but keeping the scripts and algorithm secret, is there a way to encrypt that or any other way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Lots of discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707276/encrypting-r-script-under-ms-windows

Comment: @Joyce, to hide the code, a standard solution is to distribute the application on a server. So, your users would connect via server. Not only would you be able to hide the code, but your users would also always have access to the most updated version. However, you would need to establish server infrastructure (probably best to use an R cloud provider).

Comment: Creating a package would help to distribute the common code. I too have been looking into creating an exe for mundane tasks/functions, calcs that repeats over again and again. And to share an exe with some who do not use coding/prefer a UI based app. Unfortunately still looking for ways.

Comment: 2


I don't see why R can't be compiled, if Python can do it. Python is technically interpreted, but their are compilers that bundle the interpreter with the code and compile into an exe.

Comment: @bonCodigo Have you found a way yet?

Comment: A new alternative in early stages is ShinyLive, which will convert a Shiny script (which could be an interface to an R script) into WASM (web assembly) so it can be run in any browser. https://posit-dev.github.io/r-shinylive/

Answer (score 43):

As a matter of fact there is a way to achieve solution that would meet your requirements. Have a look at the article on Deploying [Desktop Apps with R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/) on R-Bloggers. As detailed in the article, you will end up using a few more things than a single exe file.

Also I would like to draw your attention to the [RGtk2](http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/) with use of the [RGtk2](http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/) you could attempt to develop your own interface in R. If push comes to shove, I trust that you could pack your R code together with a portable version of R and dependencies into one installer and make and app from that, that would create an illusion of a single exe file.

In your question you asked whether it's *easy* to develop a standalone executable file interpreting R code. I wouldn't say it's easy. If you have a strong desire to run a R code from an application, you could do it in a simpler manner using [RCaller](https://github.com/jbytecode/rcaller) for Java or [R.NET](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The linked article on deplying desktop apps with R is really good (uses portable apps and shiny!), Thx!

Comment: @RYoda I'm glad to read that. There is interest in this subject. If you want to stick with Shiny, [this article](http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html) provides interesting advice on packaging a Shiny App as a Windows Desktop App.

Comment: it is also possible to use RCaller scripting engine throughout the javax.script API, see http://mhsatman.com/rcaller-3-0

Comment: note that the [CRAN listing for RGtk2 is gone](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGtk2/index.html), so that solution is probably deprecated

Comment: This works  but still the code can be accessed and modified.

Answer (score 12):

In response to your comment:

> Actually I would like to distribe it but keeping the scripts and
>   algorithm secret, is there a way to encrypt that or any other way to
>   achieve this purpose?

You can (sort of) do this by saving functions using `save()`. For example, here's a function `f()` you want to keep secret:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  return(x + y)
}
```

Save it wherever:

```
save(f, file = 'C:\\Users\\Joyce\\Documents\\R\\Secret.rda')
```

And when you want to use the function:

```
load("C:\\Users\\Joyce\\Documents\\R\\Secret.rda")
```

I would save all my functions in separate files, put them in a folder and have one plain old .R script loading them all in and executing whatever. Zip the whole thing up and distribute it to whoever. Maybe even compile it into a package. Effectively the whole thing would be read-only then.

This solution isn't that great though. You can still see the function in R by typing the name of the function so it's not hidden in that sense. But if you open the .rda files their contents are all garbled. It all depends really on how experienced the recipients of your code are with R.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, can be one way to prevent others directly seeing the codes, thanks again.

Comment: But it will appear once you type `f` .

Answer (score 8):

I have done some research on this issue and a few solutions were implemented in the last few years.

1. One option is to wrap your app along with a portable R into a container application like Electron. The [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/COVAIL/electron-quick-start) project tries this.
2. The [RInno package](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/03/rinno-how-to-install-local-shiny-apps/) provides functions to bundle your app and R portable into an installer app. Every user runs the installer on their system once which will install your app, the packages and the code. But in the end users may not see the difference to other apps. They get a link in the start menu and that's it. I did that successfully. But it did not work out of the box. I had to adjust the output manually in several places.
3. A second container solution works with docker. That is what [ShinyProxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/documentation/getting-started/) does. See also this [blog](https://www.databentobox.com/2019/11/05/deploy-r-app-with-shinyproxy/).
4. The package [shinyShortcut](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyShortcut/readme//README.html) (I quote) "will produce an executable file that runs the shiny app directly in the user's default browser".

Important to note: I haven't tested most of them. From reviewing the solutions I often get the feeling that these solutions might make releases somewhat complicated because there are always manual steps involved.

Answer (score 5):

One form of having encrypted code is implemented in the `petals` function in the TeachingDemos package.

Note that it would only take intermediate level programing skills to find the hidden code, however it does take deliberate effort and the user would not be able to claim having seen the code by accident.  You would then need some type of license agreement in place to enforce any no peeking agreements.

Comment: Thank you Greg, i just look into the function you mentioned, but cannot figure out how to use that to hide the codes, would you kindly elaborate more?Thanks much.

Comment: @Joyce, the `petals` function does not hide code, it is one example of having a key piece of code hidden (can you read the key piece?).  Other tools are needed to do the encrypting(bleaching).  A simpler approach is discussed at: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-October/062236.html.  Byte compiling may help as well, but you really need some type of license agreement.

Answer (score 4):

Well you are going to need R installed on the deployment machine. As for making an executable, I'm not sure that's possible. But you can create another program that invokes your R script. R is an interpreted language. It is not possible.

Comment: Do we have any news on any R compiler? I started using python and there are easy ways to produce exe files (py2exe and cx_freeze for example). Is there any chance to see something like this in R soon?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no direct way of compiling R as an exe.

What you can do is to create an `.exe` **installer** using NSIS that bundles the required packages, as well as your code. This is then installed to your desired destination with a desktop shortcut and icon if needed (the computer just needs the right R version to be installed).

### Example .nsi script

I use an .nsi script, which is executed from R using glue to fill in some extra values.
You need to have [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download) installed and have all your files in the specified folders (build in the example below)...

In the file `base_template.nsi`, I have

```
Unicode true
!define ZIP2EXE_NAME `{{APPNAME}}{{VERSION}}`
!define ZIP2EXE_OUTFILE `{{DIR}}{{VERSION}}.exe`
!define ZIP2EXE_COMPRESSOR_LZMA
!define ZIP2EXE_INSTALLDIR `$DESKTOP\{{APPNAME}}`
!include `${NSISDIR}\Contrib\zip2exe\Base.nsh`
!include `${NSISDIR}\Contrib\zip2exe\Modern.nsh`
!insertmacro SECTION_BEGIN
File /a /r "{{SRCFOLDER}}"
!insertmacro SECTION_END
Section "Start menu shortcut"
CreateShortcut "$desktop\{{APPNAME}}.lnk" "$instdir\{{APPNAME}}.cmd" "" "$INSTDIR\icon.ico" 0
SectionEnd
```

Which can be read into your R session like this

```
file <- "base_template.nsi"
nsi <- readLines(file)
APPNAME <- "My App"
VERSION <- "v0.1"
DIR <- "\Users\david\myapp" # the path and name to the outfile
SRCFOLDER <- "build" # copy all your files that are needed here
# also make sure that you have an "My App.cmd" (for windows)
# also make sure that you have and icon.ico in the SRCFOLDER
nsi_file <- "base_file.nsi"
writeLines(glue::glue(nsi), nsi_file)

# execute NSI

exe <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/NSIS/makensis.exe"
cmd <- sprintf('"%s" %s', exe, nsi_file)

res <- system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
```

For completeness sake, I also have a short `.cmd` script that then starts the app, this needs to be in the build directory as well
`My App.cmd`

```
@echo off

:: find the most recent version of R
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "C:\Program Files\R" /B /ON /D') DO SET rv="C:\Program Files\R\%%i\bin\Rscript.exe"
echo Using R Version: %rv%

%rv% app.R

set /p DUMMY=Hit Enter to exit
```

Comment: I have done similar approach using `Inno Setup compiler`. But How hard would it be to compile `R` scripts to .exe what are the possible block in creating something like that. If `R` can be converted into `C` or `C++`  and then compiled into `.exe`. If some kind of parser is there, then this would be a possible approach.

Comment: There is R wasm ([webR](https://github.com/r-wasm/webr)), which compiles R to wasm using Emscripten, so it should be possible in theory, I just didnt see it yet. Maybe this is topic you can raise with the maintainers of webR.

Comment: I think this the most possible option compile R into an executable