# compile and pass R program to exe

Tags: r, compiler-construction, exe

I have written a program which read from a .xlsx and output a .csv file. And now I need to handover this program to my colleague, who knows nothing about programming.
Although I can help her installing R and ask her to hit "Ctrl+Enter" every time, but i think i  should better compile the program into a executable file so with double-clicking the file, all done.

I have searched for a little bit on how to compile a R program, but still can't find a good answer, do you have any suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: I did a quick Google search and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096520/compile-r-script-into-standalone-exe-file  Maybe it will help.

Comment: You could start you're program when R starts. You add a small GUI that he can use and then when the R starts your program automatically starts also. That's doable.