# Is it possible to hide R code or deliver in exe format so that USER does NOT get to see the code?

Tags: r

Is there a provision in R or in other free tools such as RStudio which can hide the R code (does NOT show to USER) and still perform it's intended job by taking specific pre-defined inputs from USER? 
I have written a few lines of R code which takes an input from USER and produce an output in terms of table and a graph. Is there any way I can protect (hide) this code from USER while the user runs this code as per given instructions? Making R package could be a way however is it totally fool proof (User doesn't get to see the code inside function)?
Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252065/sharing-r-functionality-with-multiple-users-without-exposing-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707276/encrypting-r-script-under-ms-windows

Comment: Why not embrace that R is an open source system where everybody has the opportunity to study, validate and enhance the source code?

Comment: The people who develop(ed) R believe in open source. Therefore, the design decisions they took make it impossible to make R source code inaccessible to a user who runs it on his system. You could run R on a server and only serve the results to your users.