# Is it possible to protect R code with a Bash script?

Tags: r, bash

I have an R script some colleagues have to run in order to speed up some calculations. This script is written in R. I would like to let the code be secret. The calculations have to be run on a public folder on a server on which we all have a common password to connect to it. I usually share my code but in this case I would like to protect it.

How is it possible? I know that it is possible to create a Bash script but I don't know how to set the path to the script so that people can not access to it but at the same time they are able to run it. I tried using MacFort or to protect the folder in which there's the code with a password from Disk Utility. However to run the code I have to mount the folder and in this way people access to it.

Comment: "I would like to let the code be secret" - Why? Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096520/compile-r-script-into-standalone-exe-file

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/32667805 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10252065