# is there any possible way that i could protect my R source code?

Tags: r

Just wanted to know is there any possible way that i can protect my source code which is written in R Language, since now we are planning to host our application on clients server.
I would appreciate if some one could help me out with protecting the source code.

Comment: Not clear what you mean exactly by: `"protecting the source code"` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096520/compile-r-script-into-standalone-exe-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707276/encrypting-r-script-under-ms-windows

Comment: Once i make a package of R project the source code of the code is easily visible and readable even i tried creating a binary package even though if we install the package on R studio am able to view all the code which are present in the project. Need to find a way to make the code not visible once i make a package out of it. I think now u get the point if not let me know. Thanks in advance!!